# How are drugs encapsidated?

Tags: virus, therapy

I recently came across "**[drug encapsidation](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ja071896b)**".

So far, I have come to understand that it is a technique to insert drug particles/molecules in the protein shell of a virus, namely the [capsid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capsid).

But I cannot find a simplified explanation on how to perform it? On contrary, for  [**drug encapsulation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liposome), there are many online materials and resources.

**My questions are:**

1. How does one perform the encapsidation?
2. Are the virus gene in the capsid removed and the drug encapsidated?
3. How does a drug which is masked as a virus not get detected by the body's defense mechanism?

Comment: Where did you come across drug encapsidation?

Comment: @CareyGregory I have included a link to drug encapsidation in the body.